# ARKit and SceneKit. How to trigger action/play_video as per detected image anchor physical width in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, arkit

I'm able to detect object in image using ARKit and after that i'm triggering an action to play video as per the image size(physical size of detected size).

The problem is video size is not adjusting properly as shown in below screenshot.
[image]

Here is the code which i tried. let me know anything is missing/wrong in handleFoundImage function.

```
var scnNodeBarn: SCNNode = SCNNode()
var currentNode: SCNNode? = nil
var currentARImageAnchorIdentifier: UUID?
var timer: Timer!

/// - Tag: ARImageAnchor-Visualizing
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
    let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
    let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name!
    print("you found a \(name) image")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = "You are watching  \"\(name)\""
    }
    // The following timer fires after 0.6 seconds, but everytime when there found an anchor the timer is stopped.
    // So when there is no ARImageAnchor found the timer will be completed and the current scene node will be deleted and the variable will set to nil
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if(self.timer != nil){
            self.timer.invalidate()
        }
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.6 , target: self, selector: #selector(self.imageLost(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    // Check if there is found a new image on the basis of the ARImageAnchorIdentifier, when found delete the current scene node and set the variable to nil
    if(self.currentARImageAnchorIdentifier != imageAnchor.identifier &&
        self.currentARImageAnchorIdentifier != nil
        && self.currentNode != nil){
        //found new image
        self.currentNode!.removeFromParentNode()
        self.currentNode = nil
    }
    //        updateQueue.async
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        //If currentNode is nil, there is currently no scene node
        if(self.currentNode == nil){
            handleFoundImage(imageAnchor, node, nameVideo: "Cup.mp4" )
        }
        self.currentARImageAnchorIdentifier = imageAnchor.identifier
        // Delete anchor from the session to reactivate the image recognition
        self.sceneView.session.remove(anchor: anchor)
    }

}

private func handleFoundImage(_ imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor, _ node: SCNNode, nameVideo: String) {
    let name = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name!
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = "You are watching  \"\(name)\""
    }
    let size = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize
    let documentsPathURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let videopath = documentsPathURL?.appendingPathComponent("/3DScenes/\(nameVideo)")
    // 2
    let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videopath!)
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
    avPlayer?.play()
    // 3
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
        object: nil,
        queue: nil) { notification in
            self.avPlayer?.seek(to: .zero)
            self.avPlayer?.play()
    }
    // 4
    let avMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    avMaterial.diffuse.contents = avPlayer
    // 5 HERE NEED TO MAKE CHANGE TO PLAY/DISPLAY AS PER IMAGE SIZE
    let videoPlane = SCNPlane(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    videoPlane.materials = [avMaterial]
    self.scnNodeBarn.transform = node.transform
    scnNodeBarn.geometry = videoPlane
    scnNodeBarn.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(self.scnNodeBarn)
    self.currentNode = self.scnNodeBarn
}


    @objc func imageLost(_ sender:Timer){
    self.currentNode!.removeFromParentNode()
    self.currentNode = nil
}
```

How can i display/play/show video as the same of image anchor physical size in swift iOS

Comment: @KNV . Please answer if you the solution.

Comment: @BlackMirrorz . Please answer if you the solution